# how to split single column values into multiple columns based on other column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to split single column values into multiple columns based on another column value, I could get it but I am unable to remove the additional null values I get

**table**

```
create table tbl1
(id int, strtype varchar(50), strvalue varchar(20));

insert into tbl1 values
(1, 'name', 'a'),(1, 'value', 'a1'),(1, 'name', 'b'),(1, 'value', 'b1');
```

**Desired output**

```
NAME    VALUE
a       a1
b       b1
```

**sql i tried**

```
select 
(case when strtype='name' then strvalue end) as name,
(case when strtype='value' then strvalue end) as value
from tbl1
```

Comment: can u provide more information about what u want to do ? Your explanation is little bit confusing

Comment: How are a and a1 related (as well as b and b1) in the data?  Does the value always start with the name + some additional characters?  Or are the IDs supposed to be the same between name and value?  Or are you trying to do it based on the order they were inserted?  Based on that we can find a solution for you.

Comment: @ArunPrasanth: Read question properly

Comment: I need to get strvalue having 'name' in strtype in one column and strvalue having 'value' in strtype in another column. Hope this clarifies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the below script and hope this help you:

```
Select t1.strValue , t2.strvalue from tbl1 t1 inner join tbl1 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
where t1.strtype = 'name' and t2.strtype = 'value' and t1.strvalue = LEFT(t2.strvalue ,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If am not wrong this should help you.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   tbl1) a
       PIVOT (Max(strvalue)
             FOR strtype IN (name,value)) pv
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   tbl1) a
       PIVOT (Min(strvalue)
             FOR strtype IN (name,value)) pv
```